# UIBarbuttonItem dismiss UIVIewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

I added an extension to UIViewController to add a close button

```
    extension UIViewController {
      func addCloseButton() {
            let button = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "bar_close"), 
                                         landscapeImagePhone: nil,
                                         style: .done,
                                         target: self, 
                                         action: #selector(UIViewController.dismiss(animated:completion:)))
            navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button
      }
    }
```

When i tap the barbutton i get a crash directly to AppDelegate.
Any hints? Seems related to the selector.

Comment: Have you declared "dismiss" method ?

Comment: Thats a method from UIViewController...i didnt declare it of course

Comment: declare in extension UIViewController {.... and check

Comment: ? im trying to call UIVIewController dismiss method, i dont get your point trying to override it.

Comment: it is bad practice to use method like this you should use protocol instead

Comment: @Godfather if you want example then i can post as answer. but you need some minor changes to do.

Comment: I dont want to go to delegation for dismissing the vc from outside. You can actually dismiss your self ->         dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil) and thats what i want to do.

Comment: **I dont want to go to delegation for dismissing the vc from outside** You are understanding that protocol is only for delegation then sorry to say you are 100% wrong you should go through some tutorials which describes how POP works :) will post an example as answer for your ref.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use **dismiss(animated:completion:)** as selector here because it takes two arguments bool and closure and bar button action pass args as UIBarButtonItem which cause app crash.
so change your code like this.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func addCloseButton() {
        let button = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "rightgreen"),
                                 landscapeImagePhone: nil,
                                 style: .done,
                                 target: self,
                                 action: #selector(onClose))
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button
    }

    @objc func onClose(){
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

However this question has accepted answer which load extra one method `addCloseButton` in each and every viewcontroller still posting a answer will going to help someone

NOTE : This example for adding barbutton item automatically and also handle action for pop view controller.

As Protocol extension doesn't provide a to implement selector methods so to get the rid of it I have created this solution.

First thing you need is `BaseVC` which  is subclass of `UIViewController` and all of your view controller going to be inherited by `BaseVC` like your `class LoginVC:BaseVC` ...

now declare protocol

```
protocol PopableClass {
  func popSelf (animated:Bool)

}

extension PopableClass where Self : UIViewController {

    func popSelf (animated:Bool)  {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: animated)
    }

}
```

In your Base VC add two methods and call  `setupNavigationBar` from `viewDidLoad`

```
func setupNavigationBar () {

    if self is PopableClass {
        let barbuttonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "back"), landscapeImagePhone: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "back"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(popViewController))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barbuttonItem
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

@objc func popViewController () {
    if self is PopableClass {
        (self as! PopableClass).popSelf(animated: true)
    }
}
```

You did it !!

Now in whatever class you need back button to pop view controller just use like this

`class PushedClass: BaseVC,PopableClass`

Hope it is helpful